# mPDF generates thousands of empty pages from URL

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, mpdf

I try to generate a PDF from an http URL. I followed the tutorial at https://mpdf.github.io/real-life-examples/pdf-from-every-page-of-website.html

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => '/temp/pdf', 'format' => 'A4', 'mode' => 'utf-8']);
$mpdf->setBasePath($url);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/../temp/pdf/test.pdf','F');
```

What I get is a PDF with 2202 empty pages.

EDIT:
If I remove the reference to ***bootstrap.min.css*** (Bootstrap 4) in my html file, the content is not formatted correctly, but otherwise displayed correctly (just 2 pages).

Answer (score 1):

mPDF does not support bootstrap, i believe 2202 pages come from  `file_get_contents('bootstrap.min.css')`

Comment: Thanks - Do you have any detailed information on your assertion?

Comment: That it does not support bootstrap is one thing, but it should recognize that it is a css-file and not generate all these empty pages :-( (I have the same issue)

Comment: I am running into this same issue.  Using bootstrap 4 with Wordpress. However, I am not sending my head or footer to mpdf.  I'm hiding all of that because I don't want it printed.  I believe bootstrap css is not being sent to mpdf at all, but I'm still getting thousands of empty pages.

Comment: I realized i was sending my stylesheet in the form and that i was compiling bootstrap into my main stylesheet.  So, i tested removing that and TADA i got a page to print to a pdf.  Thanks for this answer!